# How do I safely ground and bond my circuit?

Tags: electrical, grounding, circuit

I'm trying to design and install a very simple little off grid power setup for a one room cabin. It would have a main solar power source and a backup generator. I'm trying to design a simple AC circuit I could plug either power source into.

Now I'm to grounding and bonding. I've watched a handful of videos and read a bunch of stuff and I'm still confused. There seems to be contradictory information and many different opinions. Some stemming from misunderstandings and misues of terminology it seems.

These articles are great:
https://diysolarforum.com/resources/grounding-made-simpler-part-1-ac-houshold-grounding.157/

Here's what I think I understand. For my application grounding has two main purposes:

1. Earth grounding: protection from lightning
2. Bonding neutral to ground: protection from static build up

Here are three questions:

1. Are both of these necessary?
2. Both sources that have a floating neutral do I have to bond these somewhere?
3. Earth ground seems a little more straightforward in that I need to drive a grounding rod and connect the system. Still trying to determine where/how to tie the system to earth ground?

[image]

Comment: Bonding neutral to ground has nothing at all to do with protecting against static buildup.

Comment: Maybe you could help answer what it is for or point me to information?

Comment: What loads are you trying to power, and where on this planet are you, generally speaking?

Comment: US. Small loads like starlink modem, router, laptop charger, TVs.

Answer (score 2):

Neutral and safety ground are connected (bound) at one place ***only***: the master electrical panel.

Neutral carries current under normal operation, and if there is a fault neutral can become energized. Safety ground exists to  provide a route to ground that does *not* normally carry current; its purpose is specifically to absorb any current that might escape before it tries to ground itself through a human.